# Select Query with MAX

Tags: php, select, mysql

i've got a big Problem and i was trying the whole day and did not find any Solution. Hope you can help me?

I have two tables:

The first one named "orders":

```
orders_id | orders_date | .....
1           xxxxxxxxxx
2           xxxxxxxxxx
3           xxxxxxxxxx
```

The second is "orders_history":

```
orders_id | order_status_id | date_added
1           1                 2009-10-01
1           2                 2010-01-01
2           1                 2010-02-01
3           1                 2010-02-01
```

So now i want to have all orders where order_status_id = '1'

I have tried with MAX, HAVING, GROUP BY, ... Subselects also, but i haven't found any solution. I know it's not very hard, but i'm finished...
Is it something like:

```
SELECT orders.*, orders_history.* FROM orders, orders_history WHERE orders_history.order_status_id <= '1'
```

But then i also get Order with order_id 1

Hope you can help. Thank you!

Sascha

To further clarify, the poster's 'orders_history' table keeps track of the state of all orders over time. The goal is a query that will find all orders that *currently* have an order status of 1. Order ID# 1 currently has a status of 2, so it should not be included in the results.

Assumably, order status goes up over time and never goes down, so that the order status and date_added will constantly increase.

Comment: If you just want order_status_id of 1, make it '= 1', not '<= 1'.

Comment: Isn't one question mark enough!?!?!?!?

Comment: What about duplicate handling?

Comment: There is some confusion about how you determine what state an order is in. Is it based on the MAX(order_status_id) or the MAX(date_added)?

Comment: I've edited the question to add my understanding of the problem. @codeworxx - check that I am correct.

Comment: @Scott Saunders: Why do you assume that the order status will always increase? I don't think that this is an obvious assumption, and I don't think it was implied in the original question. (Edit: oh now I see codeworxx made a comment stating that)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it for you:

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders
   , orders_history
WHERE orders.orders_id = orders_history.orders_id
AND orders.orders_id IN (
  SELECT orders_id 
    FROM orders_history
   GROUP BY orders_id
   HAVING MAX(order_status_id) = 1
)
```

Comment: +1: This is a little simpler mine. Note that this query ignores the date_added though, so if an order goes to state 1, then state 2 and then back to state 1, this query won't find it. But the OP implied in a comment that the state can only increase so this may not be a problem in practice.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not surprised you had trouble getting this to work - it's a very tricky type of query where you must 'GROUP BY' and find the MAX and also all the other corresponding values in the same row. This is a common request, and it often surprises people that it's actually quite difficult to express this in SQL. Here's one way to do it in MySQL:

```
SELECT T2.orders_id FROM (
    SELECT orders_id, MAX(date_added) AS date_added
    FROM orders_history
    GROUP BY orders_id
) AS T1
JOIN orders_history T2
ON T1.orders_id = T2.orders_id AND T1.date_added = T2.date_added
GROUP BY T2.orders_id, T2.date_added
HAVING MAX(order_status_id) = 1
```

Here I am assuming that:

- orders_id, date_added is not unique.
- orders_id, date_added, order_status_id is unique.

If not the second assumption is not true, add DISTINCT after the first SELECT.

Here are the results I get for your test data:

```
2
3
```

You can join this to your orders table if you want to fetch extra information about each order.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited** after discussion in comments (changed the where clause):

```
SELECT orders.*, orders_history.* 
FROM orders INNER JOIN orders_history
 ON orders.orders_id = orders_history.orders_id 
WHERE orders.orders_id IN 
   (SELECT orders_id FROM orders_history 
   GROUP BY orders_id 
   HAVING MAX(order_status_id) = 1)
```

Comment: No, he wants to relate the tables using only the max(order_status_id)

Comment: @Scott Saunders - I'm not sure what you mean by that. Quoting from the question - "So now i want to have all orders where order_status_id = '1'".

Comment: The OP doesn't specify this clearly. But that's the point of the order history table. Orders go through stages and he wants to find all the orders that are currently at stage 1, not all orders that have ever been at stage 1. The question may be poorly presented, but I've done similar things, so I figured out what he was trying to do.

Comment: i only what the orders with MAX(status_id) = 1 !!! in my example order with id 2 and 3 and NOT order with id 1, because this has MAX(status_id) 2!!

Comment: I believe someone's given you an answer that should work in the meantime (i.e. while we were clarifying :) ). But just another question - how about considering adding a current_order_status to the orders table and not just storing it in the history table?

Answer (score 0):

```
select o.*, oh.* 
from orders o
inner join orders_history oh on oh.orders_id = o.orders_id
where oh_orders_status = 1
```

should do the trick.  It's a while since I touched mysql though, so I don't know if your orders_status should be in quotes - I'd guess not if it is an int...

Comment: No, he wants to relate the tables using only the max(order_status_id)

Comment: And where does the op outline this requirement?  The only mention is that hes tried to use MAX, but he doesn't outline why.  From the data he provided, he will only get a single result for each record anyway, assuming your assumption is correct

Comment: Yes, but i ONLY want to have the orders WHERE order_status_id = '1'
means that i will only get 

order_id = 2 and 3 as result and NOT order_id = 1 because with that id, the biggest status is 2 and NOT 1!

Comment: The OP doesn't specify this clearly. But that's the point of the order history table. Orders go through stages and he wants to find all the orders that are currently at stage 1, not all orders that have ever been at stage 1. The question is poorly (horribly) presented, but I've done similar things, so I figured out what he was trying to do.

Comment: Oh, I see. Can he add that into the question please? Or someone with enough rep to do that should add it?

Comment: I agree the OP is poorly worded, but after reviewing Scott is correct.